# How to find which input field is modified?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, input

I have couple of input field and values in them. This is projected to the user.
The user can modify these values and submit them.
When submitted, I need to check which input field is modified.

I can compare the previous fields and current fields and check. But I am trying to find more optimized way to do this.
I can use javascript, php, jquery and html tricks

Comment: what do you exactly mean by modified? since when? do you mean different from the database-stored value or something else?

Comment: ^^^ +1 Do you mean client side change or changing data in the DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input id="input1" value="someValue" type="text">
<input id="input2" value="someValue" type="text">
```

**Script:**

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert("input field is modified : ID = " + id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 different input, 1 hidden with a class like `originalVal` and 1 visible for every input.

Then on submit you do something like that :

```
$('input').each(function(){
     var currentVal = $(this).val();
     var originalVal = $(this).closest('.originalVal').val()
     if(currentVal  != originalVal){
          //This input has changed
     }
})
```

Comment: But he said... "I can compare the previous fields and current fields and check. But I am trying to find more optimized way to do this. I can use javascript, php, jquery and html tricks"

Comment: Well there's not an optimized way to do this since if you use `.change` event, it will trigger when he change the value, but if you revert back for the old value, the input will be considered as changed even if it's not... So yeah in my opinion, this is the optimized way and I confirm that his first way to do this was the right one...

Answer (score 0):

Since no code was given, you could compare what was in the input compared to what is now in it.

HTML Input:

```
<input type="text" id="testInput" value="DB Value"/>
```

jQuery

```
var modifiedInputs = [];
var oldVal = "";

$("#testInput").focus(function() {
    oldVal = this.value;
}).blur(function() {
    console.log("Old value: " + oldVal + ". New value: " + this.value);

    //If different value, add to array:
    if (this.value != oldVal) {
        modifiedInputs.push(this.id);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/tfmVk/1/

Edit: Took it a step further, on modification of an input, if the changed value is different from the original, it pushes the elements ID to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet would be to get the initial values from the input fields, and then compare them later on. Then, just do a comparison once the submit button is clicked. For instance, put this somewhere in your $(document).ready() that way it will retrieve the initial value.

```
var oldValue=[];
$('input').each(function(){
    oldValue.push($(this).val());
});
```

Then you can compare later on when you hit the submit.

Answer (score 0):

you could compare with default value like this

```
for(var i in formObj)
    if('value' in formObj[i] && formObj[i].value!=formObj[i].defaultValue){
        //do what ever here ...
    }
```